# Google Cloud billing information verify?

Tags: google-cloud-billing

I have a problem with google cloud's billing verify. I added a debit card, which has received an X amount of eurocents from Google. To verify my billing, I need to type that amount into the 'billing account'. However, when I click 'billing' it says there are no accounts, when I try to create one, it tells me my billing account is awaiting confirmation. Any ideas?

Comment: probably easiest if you contact Google Cloud Support directly: https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/

Comment: What do you see here? https://console.cloud.google.com/billing AND https://pay.google.com/

Comment: Sorry for my late reactions. I was unaware of a billing support. Thanks for that @DazWilkin

Comment: Excuse my late reaction. It tells me to create a billing account. After which it redirects to the 300 dollar free promotion page, where it tells me my bank account is awaiting verification. @JohnHanley

Comment: The pay.google.com tells me I have a back account and a payment profile. @JohnHanley

Comment: I'm currently in the same situation. Did you manage to resolve this issue? Google Support has been unbelievably unhelpful so far.

Comment: @Protectorone I'm afraid not. I astonishes me that Google has not resolved this yet. I ended up buying a credit card, which did work.

Comment: @CookieAndPizza Would you mind to post your solution as a formal answer? This is to help other users that have a similar problem.

Comment: @RogelioMonter I could, but it's not really an answer to the question, more a workaround. I had to buy a credit card, while I originally wanted to use a debit card (which they also offer as an option)

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, including google support being extremely unhelpful. I already received the test deposit in my account, but they do not allow to enter it anywhere. The billing navigation menu points me to documentation which points me to the billing navigation menu.

Comment: @JeroenVermunt Did you directly contact a billing agent [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/)? Please notice the link to click is different if you're a [billing administrator](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/onboarding-checklist#important_roles_3) or you're not.

Comment: I solved the problem, turns out I was able to verify the account at payments.google.com

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** You could experience some issues when adding a payment method to your billing account in Google Cloud. The best you can do if you face any issue after reading the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#available_payment_methods) is to [contact Billing support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/).

> If you receive an error such as *Your card does not support automatic recurring payments* or *General decline of the card*, please select a different form of payment.

---

As I can see from your question, you tried to [verify Your Bank Account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/verify-bank), as stated in the documentation:

> A small test deposit will appear in your bank account within a few days of adding the account as a payment method. After you see the test deposit, you should verify the deposit as described in [Find and enter a test deposit](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/verify-bank#find_and_enter_a_test_deposit).
>
> ---
>
> #### Instant bank verification
>
> We offer instant bank verification for Google Cloud customers. Unlike the test deposit verification method, which takes several days to complete, instant bank verification allows you to verify your bank account within seconds.
>
> You can use instant bank verification in either of the following situations:
>
> - [If you haven't entered your bank account information yet](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/verify-bank#if_you_havent_entered_your_bank_account_information_yet)
> - [If you've recently entered your bank account information](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/verify-bank#if_youve_recently_entered_your_bank_account_information)
>
> - [Verify your payment method (US only)](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7625286)
>
> ***Note:** Currently, this service is available only to customers with a U.S. bank account.*
>
> ---

In the *[resolve errors when attempting to add or update a payment method](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#debit)* section, it mentions that

> you might receive an error such as:
>
> - Your card does not support automatic recurring payments.
>   or
> - General decline of the card. No other information was provided by the issuing bank.
>
> You might encounter these errors if you are using a debit card that requires two-factor authentication...
> When you enter a debit card as your form of payment, Google checks whether your issuing bank approves subscriptions or recurring payments using that card. If your bank does not approve, this card will not work for automatic recurring payments.
>
> If you receive an error such as  *Your card does not support automatic recurring payments*  or  *General decline of the card*, please select a different form of payment. You can also contact  [Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing)  for help.

Therefore, some of the issues when adding a payment to your Cloud Billing account could be related to some bank restrictions and could even be related to some domestic and international regulations, as it occurs to [customers in India](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#credit_and_debit_cards).

---

As stated in the [Payment Methods](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#available_payment_methods) documentation:

> The [payment methods available](https://support.google.com/paymentscenter/answer/9001356?ref_topic=9023854#allowed-methods) for your self-serve (online) Cloud Billing account depend on your [currency and country](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency). In many countries, you can set up a **credit card, debit card, or bank account** as a primary payment method.

So in the first instance, I suggest you review the [List of countries and regions](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency#list_of_countries_and_regions).

> If your country or region is not listed here, this might indicate that your country or region's currency is not supported for Google Cloud charges. In these instances, your Cloud Billing account might incur charges in USD.
>
> For countries or regions not listed here, check the [payment options tool](https://payments.google.com/u/0/paymentsinfofinder) for information.

Then, you should check the [Supported payment methods](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#supported_payment_methods):

> *The types of cards Google services lets you add to payment profiles vary by location and by product.*
>
> - American Express
> - MasterCard
> - Visa
> - Discover (U.S. only)
> - JCB (Japan and U.S. only)
> - Visa Electron (Outside the U.S. only)
> - Elo credit cards (Brazil only; We don't allow you to add Elo debit cards)
> - Debit cards with the Visa or MasterCard logo
>
> **[Bank account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#bank_account)**
>
> [If supported in your country](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency), you can add a bank account to pay.google.com to pay your Cloud Billing account.
>
> #### Verify Your Bank Account
>
> Depending on your country, you might need to verify your bank account to use it as a payment method by direct debit. A small test deposit will appear in your bank account within a few days of adding the account as a payment method. After you see the test deposit, you should verify the deposit as described in [Find and enter a test deposit](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/verify-bank#find_and_enter_a_test_deposit).

Also, there are some [unsupported payment methods](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#unsupported_payment_methods):

> - Debit cards that  [require two-factor authentication](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#debit)
>   are not accepted for payment.
> - Prepaid cards and Virtual Credit Cards (VCCs) are not accepted for payment.
> - Bank accounts that only support disbursements are not accepted for payment.
> - Payment via wire transfer is  *not*  supported for  [monthly charge or threshold billing
>   accounts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-cycle).
>   You may pay with a bank account by adding it as a payment method,  [if
>   supported in your
>   country](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency).

So, as long as your payment method is supported, you could [add it to your Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#add_a_payment_method).

See also:

- [Fix payment and billing issues](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/2523116)
- [How to fix a payment issue - YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6hG9rTuw50)